# Is there a way to manage "maxOccurs" property for sequence element in asmx service?

Tags: c#, wsdl, asmx

I'm trying to find a way "maxOccurs" property for an array in my asmx web service response.

I know there is no .NET standart way to manage that, but it can be done in WCF (svc) services via custom attributes and IWsdlExportExtension.

What i have now looks like this

Service:

```
[WebService ( Namespace = "%namespace%" )]
[WebServiceBinding ( ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1 )]
public class MyAPI : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public MyWebMethodResponse MyWebMethod ( ... )
```

Which has a return type of:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyWebMethodResponse
{
    public MyWebMethodResult [] Result;
    ...
}
```

This code generates following WSDL:

```
<s:element name="MyWebMethodResponse">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MyWebMethodResult" type="tns:MyWebMethodResponse" />
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="MyWebMethodResponse">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Result" type="tns:ArrayOfMyWebMethodResult" />
        ...
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfMyWebMethodResult">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="MyWebMethodResult" nillable="true" type="tns:MyWebMethodResult" />
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

And I want to change "maxOccurs" property of the sequence element to, for example, 100:

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100" name="MyWebMethodResult" nillable="true" type="tns:MyWebMethodResult" />
```

Comment: `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` are the xml attributes to specify how many minimum and maximum  items the particular collection can have. They do not translate to c# code